# How to connect to remote Spark cluster from python in docker

Tags: python, apache-spark, ssh, docker, paramiko

I installed Spark 2.0.0 and Python 3 in a container with user `docker-user`. Stand-alone mode appears to be working.

We have set up a Spark cluster on AWS and hadoop. With VPN running, from laptop I can ssh to the "internal IP", like

```
ssh ubuntu@1.1.1.1
```

This logs in. Then

```
cd /opt/spark/bin
./pyspark
```

This shows Spark 2.0.0 and Python 2.7.6. A naive `parallelize` example works.

Now in the Docker-backed Jupyter Notebook, do

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('hello').setMaster('spark://1.1.1.1:7077').setSparkHome('/opt/spark/')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

This apparently goes through to the cluster, because I can see the application "hello" in the Spark dashboard at 1.1.1.1:8080. It puzzles me that it has gone so far from within Docker without care for ssh, password, etc.

Now try a naive `parallelize` example,

```
x = ['spark', 'rdd', 'example', 'sample', 'example']
y = sc.parallelize(x)
```

Looks OK. then,

```
y.collect()
```

It hangs there.

On the dashboard "Executor Summary" table, I don't know exactly what to look for. But one worker whose state is `exited` has `stderr` like this:

```
16/08/16 17:37:01 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for TERM
16/08/16 17:37:01 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for HUP
16/08/16 17:37:01 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT
16/08/16 17:37:02 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: ubuntu,docker-user
16/08/16 17:37:02 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: ubuntu,docker-user
16/08/16 17:37:02 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
16/08/16 17:37:02 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
16/08/16 17:37:02 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(ubuntu, docker-user); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(ubuntu, docker-user); groups with modify permissions: Set()
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Cannot receive any reply in 120 seconds. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:216)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at scala.util.Failure.recover(Try.scala:216)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:326)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:326)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:293)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$1.execute(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:136)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:237)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:237)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:78)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:54)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:601)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:106)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:599)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.tryFailure(Promise.scala:112)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryFailure(Promise.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.org$apache$spark$rpc$netty$NettyRpcEnv$$onFailure$1(NettyRpcEnv.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anon$1.run(NettyRpcEnv.scala:239)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Cannot receive any reply in 120 seconds
    ... 8 more
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: TransportClient has not yet been set.
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.RpcOutboxMessage.onTimeout(Outbox.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$ask$1.applyOrElse(NettyRpcEnv.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$ask$1.applyOrElse(NettyRpcEnv.scala:231)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$onFailure$1.apply(Future.scala:138)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$onFailure$1.apply(Future.scala:136)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:293)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$1.execute(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:136)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.tryFailure(Promise.scala:112)
```

Note the Docker user `docker-user` may be an issue, because there server machine expects `ubuntu`. There may be further issues.

Could the Python package `paramiko` help here? I know how to use `paramiko` to create a client object, through which to issue commands etc as if I am logged into the server. But don't know how to combine that with `SparkConf` and `SparkContext`.

Various sources stop at saying `SparkConf().setMaster('spark://1.1.1.1:7077')` as if it will just work. I believe some hoops are inevitable regarding login, password, ssh, auth.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

spark driver has to be accessible from cluster, make sure you can ping the machine you are running spark driver. this is because executors will have to contact driver actively. they don't keep TCP connection alive(not scalable otherwise).

other method is to use cluster mode other than client mode.